# Criando um botão com ajax e fazendo ele executar php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um botao que toda vez que eu clico minha pagina atualiza.

```
 $btn_add='<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?plus='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></a>';
 $btn_remove = '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></a>';
 $btn_delete='<a class="btn btn-default delete_btn" href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
```

O meu `cart.php` esta todo o sistema do meu carrinho de pedidos.
No meu `checkout.php` é onde eu adiciono ou tiro itens selecionados.
e eu inseri minha `function cart();` nele.

Eu queria usar ajax para fazer que meu botao nao atualizar minha pagina.

meu script do `cart.php`.

```
if(isset($_GET['plus'])){
$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1;
if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']] < 1){
        header('Location: checkout.php');

}else{

    header('Location: checkout.php');
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']]--;
if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']] < 1){
        header('Location: checkout.php');

}else{

    header('Location: checkout.php');
    }

}

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['delete']] = '0';
    header('Location: checkout.php');
}
```

meus botoes estao dentro de um foreach loop da minha `function cart()`;

```
function cart(){
    global $conn;


    $fabric_options = '';
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM almofadas";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $tecido=$rows['tecido'];
    $id_price=$rows['id_price'];
    $fabric_options .= "<option value=''.$id_price.''>{$rows['tecido']}</option>";

    }

    $s50='50';
    $s45='45';
  if(isset($t50)){
   $_SESSION['selected']='selected';
  }

    foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
     if($value > 0){
      if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
       $length = strlen($name) -8;
       $item_id = substr($name,8 , $length);
     $query = "SELECT * 
               FROM gallery2 
               WHERE gallery2.id =".escape_string($item_id). "";
      $run_item = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
       while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_item)){ 
             $vari   = $rows['variante'];
             $num    = $rows['title'];
             $id     = $rows['id'];

             $btn_add='<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?plus='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></a>';
             $btn_remove = '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></a>';
             $btn_delete='<a class="btn btn-default delete_btn" href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
              if($rows['variante'] < 1){
              $vari="";
              }else{
              $vari = "-".$rows['variante'];
              }
              $product = '
              <td style="width:100px; "><img src="../'.$rows['image'].'" style="width:90%;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
              <td>'.$num.''.$vari.'</td>
              <td style="width:15%;">
              <select id="fabric" class="select form-control selectpicker" required="" onchange="saveChoice()" >

              '. $fabric_options . '  

              </select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select  id="size" class="select form-control selectpicker" required style="width:80%;" onchange="saveChoice()" >
              <option value="'.$s50.'">50x50</option>
              <option value="'.$s45.'">45x45</option>
              </select>
              </td>
              <td>'.$value.'</td>
              <td>R$</td>
              <td>sub.total</td>
              <td> 
              '.$btn_add.' '.$btn_remove.' '.$btn_delete.'
               </td>
               </tr>';
               echo $product;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei organizar melhor a estrutura de seus arquivos para que possa entender como funciona exatamente a utilização de ajax.

### cart.php

A primeira coisa a se fazer é adicionar algumas referências ao seus botões de ações no loop da sua função `cart`, como o tipo de ação do botão `data_action` e o id do produto `product_id`:

```
$btn_add    ='<a class="btn btn-success actions" data_action="plus" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></a>';
$btn_remove ='<a class="btn btn-warning actions" data_action="remove" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></a>';
$btn_delete ='<a class="btn btn-default actions" data_action="delete" product_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
```

### checkout.php

Logo após, adicione o script ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.actions').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr('data_action'); //identifica a ação do botão
    var id = $(this).attr('product_id'); //id do produto
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_functions.php',
        type : 'GET', 
        data: {action:action,prod_id:id}, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //Quando a ação for PLUS 
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('plus')){
                if(data.plus == 'success'){
                    //em caso de sucesso
                } else {
                    //em caso de erro
                }
            }
            //Quando a ação for REMOVE 
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('remove')){
                if(data.remove == 'success'){
                    //em caso de sucesso
                } else {
                    //em caso de erro
                }
            }
            //Quando a ação for DELETE 
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('delete')){
                if(data.delete == 'success'){
                    //em caso de sucesso
                } else {
                    //em caso de erro
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

### cart_functions.php

Esse arquivo php, ficará responsável por receber e processar a requisição ajax.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $prod   = $_GET['prod_id'];
    switch ($action) {
        case 'add':
            echo add_prod($prod);
        break;
        case 'plus':
            echo plus_prod($prod);
        break;
        case 'remove':
            echo remove_prod($prod);
        break;
        case 'delete':
            echo delete_prod($prod);
        break;
        default:
            echo json_encode(['error'=>'error']);
        break;
    }
}

function add_prod($item){
    //sua função para add
    return json_encode(['add'=>'success']);
}
function plus_prod($item){
    //sua função para plus
    return json_encode(['plus'=>'success']);
}
function remove_prod($item){
    //sua função para remove
    return json_encode(['remove'=>'success']);
}
function delete_prod($item){
    //sua função para delete
    return json_encode(['delete'=>'success']);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: fiz o que vc falou mas os meus botoes nao funcionaram...na minha pagina checkout.php é so html e la eu chamo a function cart(); essa function esta em cart.php onde só tem php. toda vez que eu clicava em algum botao na pagina checkout.php executava meu codigo no cart.php por isso que sempre estava retornando para  header('Location: checkout.php');

Comment: na pagina checkout.php eu tenho ja inserido `<script src="../../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: mas nada esta funcionando

Comment: Fiz uma correção no código javascript, tente executar agora. Lembre-se que o retorno JSON é essencial.

Comment: Eu peguei o codigo editado e mesmo assim nao funciona olha aqui meu checkout.php-> https://codeshare.io/G4Jlu e o meu cart.php-> https://codeshare.io/NntjJ

Comment: da pra editar o codigo enviado pelo navegador

Comment: Seu código está um pouco desorganizado, editei minha resposta e montei uma simples estrutura onde você poderá se organizar melhor com as funções.

Comment: eu adicionei um alert `alert('funciona');` na function do ajax a do `plus` recebi a msg, mas não esta aumentando o meu `$value` da minha sessão, o meu `$value` é a minha quantidade de determinado id / "produto"

Comment: quando vc menciona por ex: "// sua função para add" no cart_functions.php vc so descriminou o que aquela função faz ou é para eu adicionar o meu codigo para add por ex: `function plus_prod($item){
    
  //sua função para plus
    $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1;
    return json_encode(['plus'=>'success']);
}`

Comment: Seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Você adiciona seu codigo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45934/discussion-between-james-allan-and-diego-henrique).

Comment: Funcionou eu so tive que trocar `$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1;` para `$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['prod_id']]+=1;`

Comment: So faltou o meu `$value ` atualizar automatico, pq ele so atualiza qnd dou f5...mas eu vou procurar descobrir como....muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual a sua real necessidade, mas caso seja somente carregar uma página numa DIV ou SPAN, podes tentar algo assim (onde o #principal corresponde à DIV ou SPAN onde você queira carregar):

```
<a class="ajax-link"" destino="cart.php" href="#"> 
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i>
</a>
$('a.ajax-link').click(function (e){
  $("#principal").load($(this).attr('destino'));
});
```